# Problem with WIFI. wifi is not detecting in ubuntu 14.10

Tags: wireless

I installed Ubuntu 14.10
Wired connection is connecting but wifi is not detecting any additional drivers needed or update?

Comment: Enable wireless is on?

Comment: no it is not showing

Comment: check this out http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers

Comment: Are you using laptop?.Or Desktop?. in both, is wifi device enabled?.

Comment: laptop. wifi enabled